# How to move image in Applet using KeyListener?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an Applet that displays two images and allows the user to move one of them using the left/ right arrow keys (or keys a and d). On the bright side, I know I imported the images correctly because it displays both of them once I run the the program; however, once I press the left or right key an error promptly pops up and the image doesn't move as I intended. If someone could tell me what's wrong and explain the details on what I need to fix that would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class mainClass extends Applet implements KeyListener {
Image pic1, pic2;
int x=0, y=0,move=5;

public void init(){
    setSize (1600,1200);
    pic1 = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"beach king.jpg");
    pic2 = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"eye.jpg"); 
    addKeyListener(this);
}
public void start(){

}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    //setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    try{Thread.sleep(100);} 
    catch(Exception e){}
    //going to change position of pic1
    g.drawImage(pic1, x, y, this);
    g.drawImage(pic2, 0, 0, this);
}

private boolean[] keys;

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

public void update() {
    if(keys[KeyEvent.VK_A] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT]){
       x-=move;
    }
    if(keys[KeyEvent.VK_D] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT]){
       x+=move;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue with your code is that you never initialize the array `private boolean[] keys`, but since you are just trying to change the x-position of your image, it is highly impractical to use a boolean array. Instead, just update the x value whenever a key is pressed.

Your `keyPressed` function looks then as follows:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        x-=move;
    }
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        x+=move;
    }
    this.repaint();
}
```

In the last line of this method you call repaint, such that the applet actually redraws the image.

You can then leave the `keyReleased` method empty, because you don't need to reset any value. Finally, delete your `update` method, as it is never called (the other methods in your code are called because they are either specified in the super class or in the interface).